# Does anyone here know why this python code will not save the current frame in local?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using this code [here][1].

```
# PyQt5 Video player
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, pyqtSignal, QPoint, QRect, QObject
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer, QVideoFrame, QAbstractVideoSurface, QAbstractVideoBuffer, QVideoSurfaceFormat
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget, QPushButton, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPainter, QImage
import sys
import os
import os.path as osp

class VideoFrameGrabber(QAbstractVideoSurface):
    frameAvailable = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, widget: QWidget, parent: QObject):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.widget = widget

    def supportedPixelFormats(self, handleType):
        return [QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32, QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied,
                QVideoFrame.Format_RGB32, QVideoFrame.Format_RGB24, QVideoFrame.Format_RGB565,
                QVideoFrame.Format_RGB555, QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA32, QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR32,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGR24, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR565, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR555,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_AYUV444,
                QVideoFrame.Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_YUV444,
                QVideoFrame.Format_YUV420P, QVideoFrame.Format_YV12, QVideoFrame.Format_UYVY,
                QVideoFrame.Format_YUYV, QVideoFrame.Format_NV12, QVideoFrame.Format_NV21,
                QVideoFrame.Format_IMC1, QVideoFrame.Format_IMC2, QVideoFrame.Format_IMC3,
                QVideoFrame.Format_IMC4, QVideoFrame.Format_Y8, QVideoFrame.Format_Y16,
                QVideoFrame.Format_Jpeg, QVideoFrame.Format_CameraRaw, QVideoFrame.Format_AdobeDng]

    def isFormatSupported(self, format):
        imageFormat = QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat())
        size = format.frameSize()

        return imageFormat != QImage.Format_Invalid and not size.isEmpty() and \
               format.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer.NoHandle

    def start(self, format: QVideoSurfaceFormat):
        imageFormat = QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat())
        size = format.frameSize()

        if imageFormat != QImage.Format_Invalid and not size.isEmpty():
            self.imageFormat = imageFormat
            self.imageSize = size
            self.sourceRect = format.viewport()

            super().start(format)

            self.widget.updateGeometry()
            self.updateVideoRect()

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def stop(self):
        self.currentFrame = QVideoFrame()
        self.targetRect = QRect()

        super().stop()

        self.widget.update()

    def present(self, frame):
        if frame.isValid():
            cloneFrame = QVideoFrame(frame)
            cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly)
            image = QImage(cloneFrame.bits(), cloneFrame.width(), cloneFrame.height(),
                           QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()))
            self.frameAvailable.emit(image)  # this is very important
            cloneFrame.unmap()

        if self.surfaceFormat().pixelFormat() != frame.pixelFormat() or \
                self.surfaceFormat().frameSize() != frame.size():
            self.setError(QAbstractVideoSurface.IncorrectFormatError)
            self.stop()

            return False
        else:
            self.currentFrame = frame

            self.widget.repaint(self.targetRect)

            return True

    def updateVideoRect(self):
        size = self.surfaceFormat().sizeHint()
        size.scale(self.widget.size().boundedTo(size), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        self.targetRect = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), size)
        self.targetRect.moveCenter(self.widget.rect().center())

    def paint(self, painter):
        if self.currentFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly):
            oldTransform = self.painter.transform()

        if self.surfaceFormat().scanLineDirection() == QVideoSurfaceFormat.BottomToTop:
            self.painter.scale(1, -1)
            self.painter.translate(0, -self.widget.height())

        image = QImage(self.currentFrame.bits(), self.currentFrame.width(), self.currentFrame.height(),
                       self.currentFrame.bytesPerLine(), self.imageFormat)

        self.painter.drawImage(self.targetRect, image, self.sourceRect)

        self.painter.setTransform(oldTransform)

        self.currentFrame.unmap()
```

I don't have problem playing the video, the main problem is that it just won't save the current frame in my local.
class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):

```
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player Widget") 

        self.counter = 0
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.videoFrame = QVideoFrame()
        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.errorLabel = QLabel()
        self.errorLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        # Create new action
        openAction = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)        
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open video')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        # Create exit action
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('quit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exitCall)

        screenshotAction = QAction(QIcon('screenshot.png'), '&Screenshot', self)
        screenshotAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        screenshotAction.setStatusTip('Screenshot scenes')
        screenshotAction.triggered.connect(self.screenshotCall)

        # Create menu bar and add action
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        #fileMenu.addAction(newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(screenshotAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)


        # Create a widget for window contents
        wid = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)

        # Create layouts to place inside widget
        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.videoWidget)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.errorLabel)

        # Set widget to contain window contents
        wid.setLayout(layout)


        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)

    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Movie",
                QDir.homePath())
        self.path = osp.dirname(str(fileName))
        if fileName != '':
            local =QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)
            media = QMediaContent(local)
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(media)
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)

    def exitCall(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def screenshotCall(self):
        #Call video frame grabber
        self.grabber = VideoFrameGrabber(self.videoWidget, self)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.grabber)
        #self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        self.grabber.frameAvailable.connect(self.process_frame)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Taking a screenshot of image "+str(self.counter)+" ....")
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)

    
    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())

    def process_frame(self, image):
        # Save image here
        filename = "screenshot" + str(self.counter).zfill(6)
        self.path = 'C:/Desktop'
        image.save(self.path+'/{}.png'.format(str(filename)))
        self.counter = self.counter+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.resize(720, 480)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that it will not save the frame in the local it will just continue to play when I click the screenshot or ctrl+S.I also noticed that it will not pass through or call fucntionn **process_frame**. Does anyone here know what the problem is?Thanks

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a [mre] (remove anything that is unnecessary to the question, especially in the UI). Anyway, my guess is that your call to `play()` is followed too early by the restoring of the video output. You should probably do that in `process_frame`. Note that you should **not** do `sys.exit(app.exec_())` in `exitCall`, but `QApplication.quit()`.

Comment: Okay I will take you I advice on my future question here. Also, your suggestions works. Thanks